# How to change the top of the focus rect in C++

Tags: visual-c++, checkbox, mfc, focus, rectangles

I am using a CButton to create a checkbox:

```
CButton foo; 
foo.Create("This is foo", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_MULTILINE | BS_TOP , CRect(0,0,0,0), this, FOO_ID);
```

and am using DrawText function to set it as multiline and get the size of the rect for this checkbox.

```
pDC->DrawText("This is foo", -1, rect, DT_LEFT| DT_WORDBREAK | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_CALCRECT );

   CSize cSize = (rect.Width(), rext.Height())
   foo.MoveWindow(LEFT_SPACE, -1, cSize.cx + 5, cSize.cy);
```

But now the focus rectangle of this checkbox is cropped at the top:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Crystal ball says that there is another control above the checkbox and it overlaps it.  Measuring the text is not appropriate to determine the height of the control.

Comment: 1) Tell us what a `CButton` is and where it comes from. 2) Provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Try increasing the sizes of `CRect(...)` and `cSize`, then see what happens.

Comment: It seems to me you have a control too close at the top or you are in the topmost y-position of the form. Try to position your checkbox a little lower, having something different of -1 in the second parameter of `MoveWindow`, like e.g. 4

Comment: Where do you draw? In the OnPaint Event, after the button drawing? Than this is normal... You are destroying the focus rect. DRaw all by yourself.